# Socket Connection Without Knowing Port Number - Python

Tags: sockets, port

I would like to create a connection between a server and a client via socket on 2 different computers (but the question is relevant also to a connection on the same computer). I know the IP of the server, but I would like to connect without knowing the port number of the server - is there a way to do so?

for example:

```
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((127.0.0.1, " "))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
```

Is there a way to do so?
Can it also be done without knowing IP?

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a socket without knowing the port number. However, you can use the predefined port numbers in the protocol. For example, if port is not specified, HTTP uses port 80 and HTTPS uses port 443 by default.

Comment: Okay, but after the server defines the port number - how does the client know what port number is needed ?

Comment: When the server opens a server on a protocol-promised port, the client attempts to connect to that port. The port that the server opens and the port that the client connects is the same.

Comment: I understand. My Question is regarding _"the client attempts to connect to that port."_ How does the client know what the port number is?

I would like the client to be able to connect to the server without knowing in advance what the port number is - is that possible? (The server can predefined a port number but can not send this number to the client)

Comment: Hmmm... Although port scanning is required, nmap can be considered if you know the IP and are not blocked by the firewall.